# Racket Input Assistance

Tags: racket

I have an assignment to create a calculator in Racket. The user invokes calculator, gets a prompt, enters two values making up the procedure name, and a third which is a value passed to the procedure. It takes the input however it then throws an error. My intention is to have calculator call tom and passes it the list obtained from ui. inchestofeet is just a placeholder currently returning the same value its passed.

```
         (define(getInput prompt-string)(begin(display prompt-string)(read)))

         (define(inchestofeet x)(x))

         (define(ui)((list(getInput "1st part:")(getInput "2nd part:"))   (getInput "value")))


         (define(tom input-list)
            ((eval(list(string->symbol(string-append(symbol->string(car input-list)(symbol->string(car(cdr input-list))))))(caddr input-list)))))

         (define(calculator)(tom(ui)))
```

Error:

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: (inches tofeet)
  arguments.:

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with this, but here's why you get that error.

When you type parentheses in racket, they usually mean it's a function call of the form `(some-function argument ...)`. Since it's a function call, the thing after the open-paren needs to be a function. In your definition of `ui`, you have

```
((list (getInput "1st part:") ...) ...)
```

The problem is that `(list (getInput "1st part:") ...)` is not a function, but a list. The error message says `application: not a procedure; expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments`, because it's a function application, so it expected a function there. It says `given: '(inches tofeet)` because you gave it a list instead.

Another problem I see is that you say `inchestofeet` is a placeholder that is supposed to return the same value it's passed. To do that, you would do `(define (inchestofeet x) x)`, because `(x)` would be treated as a function call, and `x` isn't a function, so you would get the same error.

Also, I would recommend that you don't use `eval`. You should find some other way of supporting the operations you want. Using `eval` will lead to more problems.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to prompt a user for a string and convert that input to a procedure call? In our class we were given eval to use and I haven't really found any other effective way of doing it.

Comment: Well, to prompt a user for a string, you probably want to use [`read-line`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-line%29%29) like this: `(define input (read-line))`. If you want to prompt the user before calling it, then you would define a helper function like `get-input` that does `(begin (display prompt-string) (read-line))`, and then use `(define input (get-input prompt-string))`.

Comment: As for converting that input to a procedure call, what I would do is write a comment documenting which strings mean what, and then use a `cond` (or a `case`, `match`, or some other branching form) to do different things based on which string it is.

Comment: Have you figured out what was wrong and gotten past these paren errors yet? Have you gotten to the actual question?